# Can I use wall rail brackets with heavy handrail?

Tags: handrail

Can I use wall brackets for this type of handrail:

https://www.lowes.com/pd/2-25-in-x-12-ft-Unfinished-Wood-Handrail/1000442943

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wall bracket, I would use Rosette and, it looks great with hand-rail, also easy to attach as part of DYI.

I have handrail in my house and has this oak finished round Rosette attached to hand rail. The only different is my hand-rail in finished one. Buy any of the wood rosette whichever you like and meets your style.

[image]

Employee at Lowes can assist you what accessories you will need along with rosette.

Edited the answer after more clear. Here on wall side pic,

[image]

Hope this help!!

Comment: Thanks! Should have been more clear. I mean along the length of the railing, against the wall. Like these: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-Oil-Rubbed-Bronze-Decorative-Handrail-Bracket-16091/202034034

Comment: Instead of the the balustrades/uprights. This is for a stairwell with a wall on one side.

Comment: Ohk got it. Yes On wall side, you can certainly have that one. I have the same.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Wasn't sure they were strong enough

Comment: Welcome. You can have those bracket/s installed 4 feet apart, just like I have them. The handrail was installed by my builder. one more thing, needless  to say, you have screw them against stud.